# how to limit number of super user in django

Tags: python, django, superuser

In my django project, I want that there will be only one super user and no more super users can be create by **python manage.py createsuperuser**

Is it possible? If possible how?

Comment: Who has access to the console? And `createsuperuser` is _not_ the only way to create a superuser.

Comment: What is the actual intention here? Who do you want to protect from? Note that you can create a superuser from within `manage.py shell`, or directly in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Any person able to run `python manage.py createsuperuser` should be able to run `python manage.py dbshell` and create the super user manually in the database. So, this should be a trusted person anyway.

If only trusted persons can add superusers, then just tell them not to create multiple superusers (though I wonder what is the purpose of limiting to only one superuser).

However, if you want to prevent from creating more than one superuser by mistake with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, you can [override this command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/):

```
from django.contrib.auth.management.commands import createsuperuser
from django.core.management.base import CommandError

class Command(createsuperuser.Command):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if self.UserModel.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).exists():
            raise CommandError("There is no room for two, go your way!")
        super().handle(*args, **options)
```

Note that this won't prevent from setting a user as being a superuser from django admin interface.

If you want to completely make it impossible to create two superusers, you can add the constraint on the database level directly.

Another way to do it would be to subclass `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and define:

```
SUPERUSER_ID = 1  # or whatever

@property
def is_superuser(self):
    return self.id == self.SUPERUSER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to check number of superuser. Suppose you want 10 superusers then every time a superuser is created count if its more than 10 or not and give error/success message accordingly.

You can count superusers as follows:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    user_obj = User.objects.all()
    c = 0
    for i in user_obj:
        if i.is_superuser():
            c += 1

    if c > 10:
        return HttpResponse('Cannot add anymore superusers')
    else:
        new_user  = User.objects.create_user(username = name, password = password)
```

of course you will have to make a form to accept username and password but I have given the basic idea.
You can also use python's `threading` library to make things async

Comment: `User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).count()` would be much more efficient. Unless there is a custom User model that does not store `is_superuser`. In which case, this would look a bit more pythonic: `len([x for x in User.objects.all() if x.is_superuser])`.